# Training multiple independent Tensorflow neural networks at the same time

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, multiprocessing

I want to train a lot of different but small neural networks. Each one has its own independent dataset for training and testing so there is no relation at all between two networks.

How could that be done?

Right now I am attempting to use the multiprocessing library for python in order to open a CPU process for the training of each network.

```
import multiprocessing
model_A = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Model B architecture
])

model_B = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Model B architecture
])

model_A.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_B.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

def train_model_A():
    model_A.fit(dataset_A, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
def train_model_B():
    model_B.fit(dataset_B, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
epochs = 100
batch_size = 32

process_A = multiprocessing.Process(target=train_model_A)
process_B = multiprocessing.Process(target=train_model_B)

process_A.start()
process_B.start()

process_A.join()
process_B.join()
```

Would this be a good solution or are there better ways to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can start the different trainings as separate processes by running commands such as `$ python myscript.py --directory_for_first_training --output_for_first_training` if there is some shared code. In your case, simply run each script on its own.

I want to add something more useful for the GPU case, since tensorflow usually consumes all available GPU memory:

```
# Ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  # Restrict TensorFlow to only allocate 1GB of memory on the first GPU
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],
        [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=4096)]) # Notice here
    logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
  except RuntimeError as e:
    # Virtual devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
    print(e)
```

By adding this to each script, you can run different trainings also on GPU. The amount of memory needed is something you can figure out by try and error.

**Edit** Since the networks have nothing in common, I wonder why you want to have a parent process that need to wait for every training to stop in the first place?